# How to pass sql result set into two method?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, resultset

I want to pass sql result set into two method. Problem is two method separately execute while(rs.next) function separately. Then after one method execute other method got 0 result set. How can I pass result set into two method?

```
    public void demo(){
    /* Result set got from the corpusSentenceRetrive method */
    ResultSet rsNew=corpusSentenceRetrive(wordAll);
    method1(rsNew);
    method2(rsNew);
    }

   public void method1(ResultSet rst){
   ResultSet rs = rst;

   while (rs.next()) {....}
   }
   public void method2(ResultSet rst){
   ResultSet rs = rst;

   while (rs.next()) {....}
   }
```

When one method executed other method receive 0 result set. I want to execute both. How can I solve?

I tried store result set array list two location and use that two location result set. But that also not solved the problem.

Comment: Is it important to have `method1` executed on all the elements before calling `method2` ? Give some precision about what the methods do

Comment: @Dici Yep. Separate two work doing two method. Because result set data execute two different. couldn't implement in one method.

Answer (score 3):

Consume the data in the `ResultSet` in a single method and return `List<Whatever> whateverList`, then use this `whateverList` in your methods with real data.

Another approach may be using `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` when creating your `Statement` or `PreparedStatement` and go to the first line after calling the 1st method and before calling the 2nd method.

IMO I would use the former rather than the latter.

Comment: can you explain little bit further? I couldn't got the exact idea what you mentioned?

Comment: @Maduri you create a class, let's say `Yourclass`, then a `List<YourClass> yourClassList` and read the data from the `ResultSet` to fill `yourClassList` list, as last step you pass `yourClassList` as parameter to your methods. The code is described in [dasblinkenlight's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27174828/1065197), before the *Alternatively* paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass the raw result set to multiple methods. Make one method that reads the data from the result set, puts it into a collection of Java objects, and then pass that collection around as much as you wish.

```
class DataObject {
    public DataObject(int id, String name, String ...) {
        ...
    }
    public int getId() {...}
}


List<DataObject> readAll() {
    ... // Read the data and put it in the list
}
...
List<DataObject> data = readAll();
method1(data);
method2(data);
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite `method1` and `method2` to operate on a single row, rather than on the entire result set. Then the reader method could deal with the loop, and call `method1` and `method2` for each row returned from the database:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    singleRowMethod1(rs);
    singleRowMethod2(rs);
}
```

Comment: What if he does not want to store all that data ? Depending on the kind of treatment he is doing, it might be better do do it directly in the loop

Comment: @Dici probably OP should use two queries rather than 1.

Comment: @Dici If you do not want to store all the data, then it's best to do processing on the server and avoid expensive data transfer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I couldn't use two queries.Because huge data set execute. Difficult to execute two queries.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight can you explain little bit further?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight isn't it another solution rather than using data object? Because I don't want whole data set.

Comment: @Maduri That's the second alternative that I described in the edit: refactor the methods to take a single row from the result set, and call it from a navigation loop.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you mean within while loop call the method raw by raw? Actually within the method I'm doing huge process. Separate content some meaningful manner and store content in arrylist. Is there any solution can I follow? If that happened your mentioning way my whole method rewrite again. That is huge process :( .Isn't it another solution?

Comment: @Maduri There isn't much you can do, short of re-running the query, because JDBC is not required to store the entire data set in memory, so it wouldn't be easy to "rewind" it back. Storing data objects sounds like a relatively straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can Move resultSet cursor to before the first row using ResultSet APIs.

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM my_table");
// Move cursor forward as you normally traverse through ResultSet
while (resultSet.next()) {
    // Get data at cursor
    String s = resultSet.getString(1);
}
// move cursor before first row
resultSet.beforeFirst();`
```

Pass this resultSet to any method and iterate as usual in loops.